# React-Redux toolkit doesn't update the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a following project - GitHub - [https://github.com/VasVV/tinder-clone](https://github.com/VasVV/tinder-clone/tree/e9317a0aac64628b48af225027de0b8ad79b32e1)

There I tried to implement React Redux Toolkit but it doesn’t work as intended.
More specifically, I try to send to Redux store name and password from “SignUp” component:

```
 const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    //Prevent page reload
    event.preventDefault();

    var { name, password } = document.forms[0];
    dispatch(changeInfo(name, password));
  };
```

But it doesn’t change my Redux store. What could be wrong?

Comment: Though not the issue, I would advise you not to pick the first `<form>` element from a given page. You have access to the `event` object. Why not use `event.target` to get the `<form>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have named your *inputs* as `uname` and `pass` yet still you are using `name` and `password` names instead on the *submit* function.

Replace it with:

```
const { uname, pass } = document.forms[0];
dispatch(changeInfo(uname.value, pass.value));
```

**Note**: Consider using *controlled* inputs instead (using state).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work. Redux's state isn't changed =(

Comment: @VasiliiVakhton Please check in the redux dev tools if the action is at least getting dispatched.

Comment: the action wasn't getting dispatched due to `<button type='submit' onClick={() => navigate("/signup2")}>`. I moved "navigate" to "handleSubmit" function so now handleSubmit looks like this:
 `const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    //Prevent page reload
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch(changeInfo({ userName, password }));
    navigate("/signup2");
  };`
The action is getting dispatched but still doesn't do anything, the state remains in its initial condition'